# Why won't Wildfly listen on http port?

Tags: http, port, wildfly

**What I'm trying to do:**

I want to run Wildfly on Ubuntu (as an Oracle VM).

**The issue:**

I recently found it stopped listening on the http port. The following hopefully demonstrates that Wildfly is running and configured to listen on 8080. However, nothing is listening on this port:

```
polly@polly-VirtualBox:/opt/wildfly/bin$ ./jboss-cli.sh
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787
You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or 'help' for the list of supported commands.
[disconnected /] connect
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] [standalone@localhost:9990 /] /socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding=http:read-resource
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {
        "client-mappings" => undefined,
        "fixed-port" => false,
        "interface" => undefined,
        "multicast-address" => undefined,
        "multicast-port" => undefined,
        "name" => "http",
        "port" => expression "${jboss.http.port:8080}"
    }
}

polly@polly-VirtualBox:~$ sudo netstat -pl | grep 8080
polly@polly-VirtualBox:~$ sudo netstat -pl | grep 9990
tcp        0      0 localhost:9990          *:*                     LISTEN      1106/java
polly@polly-VirtualBox:~$ ps -ef | grep 1106
polly  1106  1036  2 09:18 ?        00:00:05 java -D[Standalone] -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /opt/wildfly/jboss-modules.jar -mp /opt/wildfly/modules org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/opt/wildfly -Djboss.server.base.dir=/opt/wildfly/standalone -c standalone.xml
polly  2477  2384  0 09:22 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 1106
```

**What I have tried:**

It seemed pointless to offset the ports because 8080, as far as I can tell, is actually free but I tried it anyway (to no avail):

```
polly@polly-VirtualBox:/opt/wildfly/bin$ sudo netstat -pl | grep 8180
polly@polly-VirtualBox:/opt/wildfly/bin$ sudo netstat -pl | grep 10090
tcp        0      0 localhost:10090         *:*                     LISTEN      3165/java       
polly@polly-VirtualBox:/opt/wildfly/bin$ curl -X GET http://localhost:10090/console/App.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Management Interface</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="app/app.nocache.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/console/images/favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body>

<!-- history iframe required on IE -->
<iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" style="width:0px;height:0px;border:0px"></iframe>

<!-- pre load images-->
<div style="visibility:hidden"><img src="images/loading_lite.gif"/></div>
</body>
</html>
polly@polly-VirtualBox:/opt/wildfly/bin$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8180
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8180: Connection refused
```

I also tried studying the logs (link below) but I can't see any obvious problem.

**My question:**

Why is Wildfly not listening on the http port?
Any suggestion what I can try next would be highly appreciated.

**Logs**

https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ao4w10eVqKCjbLJ3OQdiy_WH9Q8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While browsing your `standalone.xml` I saw you modified it quite much. For example, you removed the entire profile section compared to the default `standalone.xml`. For the web server to work, you will at least need Undertow.

so at least, you need to add:

```
<profile>

    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:1.1">
        <worker name="default"/>
        <buffer-pool name="default"/>
    </subsystem>

    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.0">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            </host>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
            <websockets/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
        </handlers>
        <filters>
            <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/10"/>
            <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
        </filters>
    </subsystem>

</profile>
```